# Is this proof for convergence correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Prove that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{q^n}=0$ for $1<q$.

Proof:
$S=\{q^n: n \in \mathbb N\}$
If $S$ is bounded above, then it must have a supremum $x$(note that this $x$ must be +).
That gives $q^n \leq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
For all $n \in\mathbb N$, $q^{n+1}=q.q^n \leq x \Rightarrow q^n \leq \frac{x}{q}<x$.
But, $x$ is the supremum of $S$. Thus, $S$ is not bounded above.
Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, for some $n_0 \in \mathbb N$,we get that $\frac{1}{n_0} <\epsilon$. Also, there must be some $t \in \mathbb N$ s.t $n_0<q^t$(as $S$ is not bounded above). Thus, we see that for all $n \geq t$,
$$\vert\frac{1}{q^n}-0 \vert \leq \frac{1}{q^t}<\frac{1}{n_0}<\epsilon$$
Thus,the proof.

I am newly learning analysis and I want to know whether this proof is correct.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is right but your first part about $S$ being unbounded is a bit too technical. You can simply say that $q^n>q^{n-1}$ since $q>1$, i.e. the sequence $\{q^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is strictly increasing. An alternative proof would be too say from here that this implies $1/q^n$ is strictly decreasing and that it is bounded below by $0$ since $q>1$. Thus the limit exists and you can compute it by letting $n\to \infty$.